# vue.js v-model validation and display field

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, vue.js, v-model

In this code:

```
<button type="button @click="editing=true">Edit</button>
<form v-show="editing" @submit="onSubmit">
   <textarea v-model="text"></textarea>
</form>
<div> Current value: {{text}} </div>

new Vue({ //...
   data: {
     editing: false,
     text: 'initial value..'
   }
   methods: {
     onSubmit: function() { if (this.value.length < 5) alert("error") }
   }
}
```

How can I make sure that {{text}} displays only a validated value? Do I have to create two data members - one for the form and another for display? that will lead to some mess in my code (I have many large forms).
Maybe there is a v-model update hook for validation?
The point of this question - if it's possible to avoid having two data members.

Comment: When exactly does validation take place? On submit or on each key stroke? What has to be displayed inside `{{text}}` when data isn't valid? Last valid value?

Comment: In this example the validation is onsubmit, but I prefer to have the validation onchange. And yes, {{text}} should hold the last valid value (like the initial value).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`v-model` for a `<textarea></textarea>` translates to:

```
<textarea
    v-bind:value="text"
    v-on:input="text = $event.target.value">
```

So the answer to your last question is no, there's no hooks. You either don't use `v-model` by implementing something like the code above or use 
a second variable to save the last valid string as you were considering in the question. The latter could go as:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    editing: false,
    text: 'Initial value..',
    lastValid: 'Initial value..',
  },
  watch: {
    text(value) {
      if (value.length > 4) {
        this.lastValid = value;
      }
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <form>
      <textarea v-model="text "></textarea>
    </form>
    <div> Current value (legth > 4): {{lastValid}} </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save the last valid input (in this case length >= 5) and update it on every keydown event, then on the submit just send the last valid value stored

```js
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data() {
  return {
   text: 'initial value..',
   lastValid: 'initial value..'
  }
 },
 methods: {
  submit() {
    alert(this.lastValid)
  },
  textChange($event) {
    let newText = $event.target.value
    this.lastValid = newText.length < 5 ? this.lastValid : newText
  }
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <form>
    <textarea v-model="text" @keydown="textChange"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" @click="submit" />
  </form>
  {{ lastValid }}
</div>
```